# vbs write from recordset

Tags: sql-server, vbscript, database-connection, oledb

I am simply trying to write the results of a query into a .txt file. I am caught up and can't seem to progress any further.

```vbs
' # writes records to a .txt file
Wscript.timeout = 600
Const adLockBatchOptimistic = 4
Const adUseClient = 3
Const writeFile = "C:\Path\CallLog.txt"
Dim strWrite, strSQL, strResult
Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.ConnectionTimeout=30
conn.CommandTimeout=30
conn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=Server;Trusted_Connection=Yes;" & _
          "Initial Catalog=Database;User ID=User;Password=Password;"
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
strSQL = "SELECT fld1, fld2, " & _
         "fld3, fld4, fld5, fld6, fld7, fld8, fld9" & _
         "FROM Database.dbo.[table]"
'conn.Execute strSQL
rs = strSQL, conn ' <- this line causes an error.
Open writeFile For Ouput As #1
Do Until rs.EOF
  strResult = rs
  Print #1, strResult
  rs.MoveNext
Loop
Close #1
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
```

Comment: what errors are you getting?

Comment: Line: 17
Char: 12
Error: Expected end of statement
Code: 800A0401
Source: Microsoft VBScript compilation error.
--
line 17, char 12 is:
rs = strSQL, conn

Answer (score 4):

This:

```
Open writeFile For Ouput As #1
```

is not VBScript. See [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5t9b5c0c%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) to learn how to create-open a txt file. The low tech standard way to write a recordset('s content) into a text file is

```
tsOut.Write oRS.GetString(adClipString, , sFSep, sLSep, "NULL")
```

That's exactly one line to mess up - provided you have opened the output file tsOut, the recodset oRS, and defined adClipString (2), field separator sFSep (e.g. "," or vbTab) and line separator sLSep (e.g. vbCrLf).

Comment: Thank you, with a combination of your help and Apollo and a tiny bit of research I was able to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 0):

Ok we're going to try something different. Try the code below:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set writeFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Path\CallLog.txt", 1)

Wscript.timeout = 600
Const adLockBatchOptimistic = 4
Const adUseClient = 3
Dim strWrite, strSQL, strResult
Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.ConnectionTimeout=30
conn.CommandTimeout=30
conn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=Server;Trusted_Connection=Yes;Initial
Catalog=Database;User ID=User;Password=Password;"
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
strSQL = "SELECT fld1, fld2, " & _
"fld3, fld4, fld5, fld6, fld7, fld8, fld9" & _
"FROM Database.dbo.[table]"
'conn.Execute strSQL
rs.Open strSQL, conn ' <- this line causes an error.

On Error Resume Next

Do Until rs.EOF
    strResult = rs
    writeFile.WriteLine strResult
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
```